# How can I save [Double] array into Realm?

Tags: arrays, double, realm

I need to save array of Double's into the Realm. But It seems to be unsupported.

```
dynamic var doubleArray = [Double]()  // error
let doubleArray2 = List<Double>()     // error
```

NSMutableArray seems to be unsupported too. I tried find solution in documentation and API but unsuccessfully. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only lists of Realm Objects can be used inside a parent Realm Object.

The easiest way to get around this would be to create another Realm Object subclass that has a Double property, and then use multiple instances of those to be saved in the parent List property.

Hope that helped!

Comment: This is how I did it but I hoped for better solution cause I have some troubles with that. But thanks, It good to know that this is the right way:)

Comment: Haha no worries! Yeah, this kind of question's been asked before and the general consensus was that while it's not all that elegant, it works perfectly fine. Glad I could help! :)